# Failed to debug your app in xamarin

Tags: xamarin.android

When I trying to run the anroid app in xamarin by live player at that time it shows the output i.e. **Falied To Debug Your App**.

I surprised that I am not getting any error then why it is not debuging.

In output windows it shows the following message i.e.

```
Start BSSTMatrimonial, Xiaomi MI MAX Player, .
Attempting connection to debug address: 192.168.1.101:37847.
Unable to deploy to Xiaomi MI MAX Player, please ensure the Xamarin Live Player app is open and the device is on the same network as Visual Studio.
Failed to debug your app.
```

I tried many things like change the release mode from debug mode, next is change the setting of the project from the properties, restart the vs by administration and many thing by checkout other solution of this title. But didnt work anything for me.

Thank You.

Comment: Are you getting build or compile errors, or is it just failing to deploy?

Comment: No I  am not getting any error. Still shows the debug failed.